# Is more data better for ML even if it causes imbalance between classes?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, dataset, unbalanced-classes

The question stems from attempting to predict if a loan in a peer-to-peer lending portal will be repaid or not.

I have a historical data set of about 32000 loans, but not all of these loans are matured yet and I have 2 options here:

Option 1 is that I could filter out the historical data about only the loans whose original maturity date has already passed. The benefit would be that it would result in a realistic balance between defaulted and repaid loans. The downside however is that it would mean keeping only 8500 loans from the data set (roughly 2500 defaults and 6000 repaid) as the data set is quite young and the loans maturing in 1 to 5 years means that the majority of them have not yet matured. Additionally, this also means that the excluded loans are the most recent ones which would intuitively also be the most interesting ones to learn from.

Option 2 is that I could filter out the historical data about the loans whose maturity date has already passed plus the loans whose maturity date has not yet passed but that have already gone into default. The benefit would be more data as I could now use 18000 loans (12000 defaulted and 6000 repaid). The downside however is that the balance between repaid and defaulted loans would no longer be realistic as it would be heavily skewed towards defaulted loans due to the tendency of peer-to-peer loans to default in the very beginning of the loan period.

Therefore, does the benefit of more data outweigh the disadvantage of imbalanced data?

Comment: It would not be the imbalance that worried me but the bias induced by selecting cases in either of these ways. 1 selects early defaulters which may not be representative 1 ignores those which have not yet defaulted.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I agree on the bias towards early defaulters in option 2, but how is option 1 biased (apart from the time bias of ignoring recent loans)? Option 1 does not ignore defaults, it just takes them into account only if the original maturity date of the loan has already passed, meaning that over the course of a specific time period the balance of defaults/repaid should be representative.

Comment: Yes you are right, I missed a crucial word.